# Windows C++ GetKeyState caps lock detector does opposite

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, hook, keylogger

I've written a simple program that listens to the caps-lock key, and shows a message box saying wether the caps lock is currently on or off.
So: user presses caps-lock, program determines what state the caps-lock is in now (on or off) and displays a message box.
What actually happens is that when the caps-lock is turned **on**, the program displays the message box saying it is **off** and vice versa.

I've read the documentation of the functions, but still don't understand this unwanted (opposite) behavior and would like to know how (and if) this can be fixed.

Here's my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

// Research/credits/references
// https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c-/83707-setwindowshookex-example.html
// http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/38617-get-the-state-of-capslock/

HHOOK _hook;

// This struct contains the data received by the hook callback. As you see in the callback function
// it contains the thing you will need: vkCode = virtual key code.
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;

// This is the callback function. Consider it the event that is raised when, in this case, 
// a key is pressed.
LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        // the action is valid: HC_ACTION.
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            // lParam is the pointer to the struct containing the data needed, so cast and assign it to kdbStruct.
            kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
            // a key (non-system) is pressed.
            if (kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_CAPITAL)
            {
                if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0)
                    MessageBox(NULL, "Caps Lock ON!", "Caps Lock", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                else
                    MessageBox(NULL, "Caps Lock OFF!", "Caps Lock", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            }
        }
    }

    // call the next hook in the hook chain. This is nessecary or your hook chain will break and the hook stops
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{
    // Set the hook and set it to use the callback function above
    // WH_KEYBOARD_LL means it will set a low level keyboard hook. More information about it at MSDN.
    // The last 2 parameters are NULL, 0 because the callback function is in the same thread and window as the
    // function that sets and releases the hook. If you create a hack you will not need the callback function 
    // in another place than your own code file anyway. Read more about it at MSDN.
    if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0)))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to install hook!", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}

void ReleaseHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
}

int main()
{
    // Set the hook
    SetHook();

    // Don't mind this, it is a meaningless loop to keep a console application running.
    // I used this to test the keyboard hook functionality.
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `GetKeyState` reflects the keyboard state the last time an input message was retrieved from the queue. `GetAsyncKeyState` reflects the keyboard state as it is when you call the function. Your hook is being called before the message is posted to the message queue, and so calling `GetKeyState` from there will always lag behind the real state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetKeyState` returns the state *before* the current key press is processed and the keyboard state updated. For example, if CAPS LOCK is OFF and you press the CAPS LOCK key, the hook gets called and `GetKeyState` reports the current state as being OFF, then the keypress gets processed and CAPS LOCK is turned on.

This is obliquely hinted in [LowLevelKeyboardProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)):

> ***Note:*** *When this callback function is called in response to a change in the state of a key, the callback function is called before the asynchronous state of the key is updated. Consequently, the asynchronous state of the key cannot be determined by calling GetAsyncKeyState from within the callback function.*

Since `GetKeyState` reflects a thread state prior to the physical one reported by `GetAsyncKeyState`, it is indirectly implied that the call to `GetKeyState` woud return the *previous* state.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. Do you have any idea how I could change my code so it is working as expected? I conclude I can't use GetKeyState in the hook callback.

Comment: @user2190492 The code is reporting when the caps-lock key is being pressed, and the *current* state of the toggle. It does not, and cannot, predict the *future* state of the caps-lock toggle, since that hasn't been effected yet (and, in fact, may never be if caps-lock has been disabled or customized in some other way). You could maybe check the state at a later time, by posting a message instead of popping the message box right away, or catching `WM_KEYUP`, or running a timer.